# Creating new struct multiple times

Tags: c++

I am struggling to find a good way to fill a buffer with new data. I have a thread producing data from the sound card, and I want to share this data with other threads through a shared Object called Rawcontainer. The container holds a mutex and a ringbuffer, but when I try to fill the buffer I have noticed that the objects I am filling the buffer with all have the same memory address, making the whole buffer useless.

```
void useBuffer(){
    //Create a new "OBject" (struct) each time this methos is called??
    SoundData *p = new SoundData();
    //Copy the data of the sound into the the struct data field
    memcpy(p->data, soundCopy, 2048*sizeof(double) );
    //Put the struct into the buffer and forget about it?
    Rawcontainer->writeRaw(p);
    //This should print a differnt adress each time the method is called?, but it dosent!
    std::cout << "Adressse fra Streamhandler:  " << &p <<'\n';
}
```

Comment: you want to print `p`, the pointer. You're printing `&p` aka "where `p` is stored", which may be the same every time

Comment: Aha! thanks alot. But if another thread is reading from the same address as i am putting new data into, there will be a problem? Its all new to me this pointers and stuff..

Comment: Yes. There will be a problem. But synchronization is a big question. You should read docs or , at least, open additional question.

Comment: And approve one of the answers please.

Comment: Thanks, i am new to this forum, how to approve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be printing just `p`, not `&p`, since `p` already contains the address of the new struct. What you're doing is printing the address of the `p` variable, which could very easily be the same each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
std::cout << "Adressse fra Streamhandler:  " << p <<'\n';
```

instead of

```
std::cout << "Adressse fra Streamhandler:  " << &p <<'\n';
```

p is already a pointer. You do not need here to take its address.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any experience in allocating memory in one thread and deleting it in a different one?

Comment: Do you want to offer me a job? If not you should start with googling. This link could be a start http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock.